# GAS Ask again for permission and Add Permissions Description

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a number of scripts running on Google Workspace. The is other users may blanket deny permissions to access sheets, email or other API calls which automatically generates an error message.

I believe this is because the permissions box does not say why it is requesting permissions only what permissions is requesting and none IT personnel will deny them for safety reasons.

So now I'm stuck with a bunch of errors and a bunch of users not correctly using the scripts i have set out messing up a lot of the forms.

I am looking for a way to ask for permissions every time a user opens a file if permissions have not been granted and add a description of why these permissions are needed for the file to work correctly.

I was hoping the UI app would allow me to insert a UI before the permissions option

example:

```js
function onOpen(e){
  try{ //or if (DriveApp.Permissions.Edit === true); if permissions can be queried.
    var d = DriveApp;
  }catch{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(
     'This Sheet requires permissions for The menu options to work correctly.\nPlease allow.'
  );
  //DriveApp.request_new_permissions(); //psudocode
  }

  var dapp = DriveApp;
}
```

I have been trying to check the permissions through code but it doesn't seem part of the API.
`Logger.log(DriveApp.Permission.EDIT === true); -> false`

Current Behaviour.

```
User opens a Spreadsheet with onOpen trigger.
The App Scipt require use of Drive API and requests user permission.
User selects Deny

Later the user opens the same Spreadsheet with onOpen trigger.
Drive API has already been denied so the onOpen trigger fails.
```

Desired Behaviour:

```
User opens a Spreadsheet with onOpen trigger.
A box pops up saying "This Spreadsheet requires the use of Drive API to create folders for you. Please allow if you wish to use this feature"
The App Scipt require use of Drive API and requests user permission.
User selects Deny.

Later the user opens the same Spreadsheet with onOpen trigger.
The onOpen trigger checks if Drive API permissions have been Aloud.
if not: 
A box pops up saying "This Spreadsheet requires the use of Drive API to create folders for you. Please allow if you wish to use this feature"
Drive API requests Permission again.
else:
The script executes normally
```

Comment: Could you provide a use case sample? If I am not mistaken what you are trying to do is to make sure that all the Drive files your scripts are going to work with have the right sharing permissions, and you want to accomplish this by showing an alert message every time the user opens the file, correct?

Comment: example only: We use a Text API for appointments. The Appointment Type and message template are stored on a different protected sheet. The types are loaded up as menu options. The user who rejected permissions does not have access to the menu options so they try to type in what the think is correct. another user who accepted permissions does it correctly and the 2 pending texts are sent, however it errors on the first as the manually typed option is not in the list of options. I want that first user to be prompted for permissions if they havnt giving them every time the open the sheet.

Comment: I know I could get around this with data validation but I don't want to punish my users for doing the correct thing of refusing permissions for something they do not understand. I'd rather explain what the permissions are for and re-prompt for permissions. Additionally Google Notifies me of Errors when permissions are denied, every time, every week... the only thing they do not tell me is who triggered the error.

Comment: I think I am not quite understanding the full behavior. Could you add a minimal reproducible example of the issue so that we can understand your main goal?

Comment: I cant post a MCVE, it requires a Google Project, Google Sheet and the code i already posted. To create your own copy the code i posted and add it to a sheet, setup the onOpen trigger and then remove the permissions you added when creating the trigger. I have posted current and desired behaviour, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have a better idea of the issue now. Can I ask how did you get to the conclusion that the users are the ones denying the permissions? I am asking because a simple onOpen trigger [would not be enough](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) to run something that requires authorization?

Comment: I think you could bypass the part of requesting authorization by simply adding an installable trigger, that way as soon as you authorize the script upon creation and any user that opens the sheet will use that same authorization.

Comment: @FernandoLara I get error reports every week. From my understanding: if a script uses any API anywhere then it will be evaluated at runtime and permissions will be requested. Additionally using a singular permission would do things like create folders with the permissions of the script (aka the permission owner will be the folder owner) which completely breaks audit trails.

Comment: example report: 2023-02-10 14:16:51 Greenwich Mean Time onOpen Authorization is required to perform that action. open 2023-02-10 14:16:51 Greenwich Mean Time.
The onOpen function only creates the Menu: `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();`